# Can't Export Const in React

Tags: reactjs

Sorry to ask such a silly question but I'm a total rookie and I'm stuck in a tutorial.

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the below:

Attempted import error: 'NavLogo' is not exported from './NavbarElements'

Thank you in advance.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link as LinkR } from "react-router-dom";
// import { Link as LinkS } from "react-scroll";

export const Nav = styled.nav`
  background: #000;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: -80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;

  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    transition: 0.8s all ease;
  }
`;
export const NavbarContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 24px;
  max-width: 1100px;
`;

export const Navlogo = styled(LinkR)`
  color: #fff;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
`;
```

Comment: what is your import statement?

Comment: You don't export any `NavLogo` from the file, but you do export a `Navlogo`. In Javascript identifiers, casing matters. Voting to close as "Unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have made a typo while exporting

your code:

`export const Navlogo = ...........`
should be:

`export const NavLogo = .......`

Comment: Thanks!!! Tha was it. I need to train my eye... Thank you again

Comment: @DUX happens......

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct title is "Can't import Const in React".

If you want to import non-default things, you must import with curly bracket ({ }). For example, to import Navlogo, `import {Navlogo} from './NavbarElements'`.

But if you have default export, i.e `export default Navlogo;`, you can do `import Navlogo from './NavbarElements'` and the imported object is `const Navlogo`. For import others const in NavbarElements file, you must do the first way with curly bracket

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing NavLogo?

It should look something like this:

```
import { NavLogo } from './NavbarElements'; // Path to file
```

Comment: Hi Yulian, thank for the prompt response. 
I'm importing it as follows.

import React from "react";
import { Nav, NavbarContainer, NavLogo } from "./NavbarElements";

Comment: The import looks good as long as NavbarElements is in the same directory. Have you tried restarting the server? I've encountered similar issues before with React not instantly recognizing new files, mostly with TypeScript.